# Communication from Lightning component to Visualforce page to custom controller

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, custom-controller

I'm following this example: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html

... and the example works great. In summary, it basically allows you to pass a value from a lightning component via vfWindow.postMessage() to a visualforce page, which is present as an iframe in the lightning component, via window.addEventListener().

I'd like to take it one step further and pass that same message/value to the custom controller that is feeding the visualforce page. I've tried accomplishing this a few ways, most recently by using an apex:actionFunction, but I cannot seem to successfully pass the message to my custom controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please note that I'm trying to do a POC using the exact code from the provided link as a "base". Since I'm newer poster to this site, please don't hesitate to ask if you need additional information.

Edit: Including all code as requested.

**Lightning component:**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="vfHost" type="String" default="my_visualforce_url"/>
    <aura:attribute name="message" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="vfMessages" type="String" default=""/>
    <div>
        <lightning:select name="Theater_Select_List" label="Theater" value="{!v.message}" onchange="{!c.sendToVF}" required="true">
            <option value="WW">WW</option>
            <option value="AMER">AMER</option>
            <option value="EMEA">EMEA</option>
            <option value="APAC - GC">APAC - GC</option>
            <option value="APAC - IN">APAC - IN</option>
            <option value="APAC - SEAN">APAC - SEAN</option>
        </lightning:select>
        <iframe aura:id="vfFrame" src="{!'https://' + v.vfHost + '/apex/Test_VFP'}" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="200"/>
        <iframe aura:id="vfFrame2" src="{!'https://' + v.vfHost + '/apex/Test_VFP2'}" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="200"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Lightning Component's JS controller:**

```
({
    sendToVF : function(component, event, helper) {
        var vfFrameArray = ["vfFrame","vfFrame2"];
        var arrayLength = vfFrameArray.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            console.log(vfFrameArray[i]);
            var vfOrigin = "https://" + component.get("v.vfHost");
            var vfWindow = component.find(vfFrameArray[i]).getElement().contentWindow;
            var message = {
                name: "com.mycompany.chatmessage",
                payload: component.get("v.message")
            };
            vfWindow.postMessage(message, vfOrigin);
        }
    }
})
```

**Visualforce Page (shown as iframe in lightning component):**

```
<apex:page controller="Test_custom_controller" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">
    <html>
        <body style="background-color: #F0F2F5">
            <strong>This gray area is Visualforce page embedded in the Lightning Component with an iframe:</strong>
            <div class="slds-form-element">
                <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="lcMessages">Messages Received from Lightning Component:</label>
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <textarea class="slds-textarea" id="lcMessages"></textarea>
                </div>        
            </div>
            <apex:form>
                <apex:actionFunction action="{!getData}" name="refPageMethod" rerender="pageBlockTable">
                    <apex:param name="thisTheaterId" assignTo="{!TheaterId}" value="" />
                </apex:actionFunction>                
                <apex:pageBlock title="This is my page block table." id="pageBlockTable"> 
                    <apex:outputpanel style="overflow:scroll;height:250px;" layout="block">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!TheaterId}"/>
                    </apex:outputpanel>
                </apex:pageBlock>        
            </apex:form>
            <script>
                var lexOrigin = "https://mycompany.lightning.force.com";
                var lcMessagesEl = document.getElementById("lcMessages");

                window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
                    if (event.origin !== lexOrigin) {
                        // Not the expected origin: reject message
                        return;
                    }
                    // Only handle messages we are interested in
                    if (event.data.name === "com.mycompany.chatmessage") {
                        var messages = lcMessagesEl.value;
                        messages = event.data.payload;
                        lcMessages.value = messages;
                        console.log(messages);
                        window.onchange = function() {
                            refPageMethod(messages);
                        }
                    }
                }, false);
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>    
</apex:page>
```

**Custom Controller I'm trying to feed the message (unsuccessfully thus far):**

```
public class Test_custom_controller {

    public String TheaterId {get;set;}

    public PageReference refPageMethod() {
        return null;
    }

    public Test_custom_controller() {
        getData();
    }

    public void getData() {

        refPageMethod();
        TheaterId = (TheaterId == null) ? 'WW' : TheaterId;
        System.debug(TheaterId);

    }

    public String getTheaterId() {
        return TheaterId;
        }
}
```

Comment: This site functions on the  basis of you providing the code you have tried alongside a specific issue you have encountered so we can assist you. Can you please update your post with a minimal reproduce able code sample and the issue you are facing?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I added my code. I'm able to pass the message (drop-down value) to the slds-textarea but not the actionFunction/pageBlockTable.

Comment: Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! I've been stuck on this for days now :(

Comment: Hi Brandon, I personally dont feel like going through all your code and pinpointing where the issue might be, maybe someone else will, however, if you were to highlight exactly what the behavior is (debugging involved) alongside a minimal reprodueable code sample, you might get a better response from the community.